# Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: selenium, pycharm

I have executed this in command line:

```
export PATH$PATH:/Users/MYNAME/geckodriver
```

but it doesn't work, always reports an error.

Comment: 1. export doesn't work on Windows. 2. correct syntax on Windows is `set PATH=C:/Users/MYNAME/geckodriver;%PATH%` to achieve what you would like to. 3. Next time, please try to do a bit of research, even by stepping a few steps back and taking a look at your problem in a broader view. Believe me, becoming familiar with the tools you have is very good for your future! (Including the OS!) 3. Welcome on SO, [please read the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help): by asking the right question, you'll get **answers**. By asking the wrong question, you only get close- and downvotes...